# Magento cache refresh Notification

Tags: magento, notifications

When ever i added or edit a catalog in magento 1.9.x.x i  got the following:
"One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Layouts. Click here to go to Cache Management and refresh cache types."

Comment: Thats a basic notification, magento index products and also keep cache data of product and other accessed pages. It is advisable to flush the cache if there are any product changes, otherwise cache will serve the old data instead of newly edited data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a default Magento behaviour. You can use observer event like 'catalog_product_edit_action'  and use this line of code in the observer model method :

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('block_html');
      return $this;
```

Comment: I have used it and it helps me.Thanks for answering.